# FileSystemWatcher remove event handler

Tags: c#, events, handler, filesystemwatcher

For some reason I can not remove an event handler from the FileSystemWatcher.

This is what I have

```
void Start()
{
     ivFileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
     ivFileSystemWatcher.Changed += 
        new FileSystemEventHandler(ivFileSystemWatcher_Changed);
}

void Stop()
{
     ivFileSystemWatcher.Changed -= 
        new FileSystemEventHandler(ivFileSystemWatcher_Changed);
     ivFileSystemWatcher.Dispose();
}
```

When I call start I start receiving the change events, but when I call stop I am expecting the events to stop but they are still being raised.

Comment: Seems you should not be unsubscribing from a "new" event handler as well and be directly referencing your delegate. It does not explicitly state that here, but the notation they use and how GC works with references I would directly reference my delegates to ensure they are removed (and not a new mediator that is not referenced). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried setting `EnableRaisingEvents` to `false`:

```
void Stop() 
{ 
     ivFileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

     ivFileSystemWatcher.Changed -=  
        new FileSystemEventHandler(ivFileSystemWatcher_Changed); 
     ivFileSystemWatcher.Dispose(); 
}
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm not convinced that's the best place for the `Dispose()`...

Comment: I added in the "EnableRaisingEvents = false" the event is still being raised.  There are ways around it by using a flag to ignore the event, however my big concern is that if the events are not being cleaned up and over time this could be bad.

Comment: Never mind I was an idiot - I never called "Stop".
Everything is working fine now.